# read extension field from tt_content with typoscript

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, bootstrap-carousel

I installed the Bootstrap Carousel Extension in my TYPO3 7.6 instance.
This added a field to tt_content which is named "konigbootstrapcarousel_slides"

Now in my typoscript I want to check/read if that filed has a value.
I want to pass this value to my Header.html partial.
And then in the partial render different html if that value for the Bootstrap Carousel isset.

I have tried many things so far ... here is one example.

```
lib.isPlugin = TEXT
lib.isPlugin {
    key.data = konigbootstrapcarousel_slides
}
```

and then in variables:

```
variables {
    isplugin < .lib.isPlugin
}
```

**UPDATE:**
got it working with:

```
lib.isPlugin = CONTENT
lib.isPlugin {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    where = (koningbootstrapcarousel_slides > 0)
  } 
}
```

I cant believe there is no way to get that kind of information out of the {_all} array

Answer (score 2):

you can't read a tt_content field with TS. The Typoscript config works only with "pages" table .

For your solution: You add a backend layout to your page and check this layout in Header.html with `<f:if condition="{data.backend_layout} == 1">`